# Reference request: integral formula for $\sum_{\text{roots }\lambda}e^{-|\lambda|^2}$

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, polynomials

Consider a polynomial $f(z)=c\prod_m(z-\lambda_m)\in\mathbb{C}[z]$.  I am mostly interested in the case where this actually lies in $\mathbb{R}[z]$, but that is not essential.  I wanted to find a nice formula for a smooth function on $\mathbb{R}$, depending continuously on the coefficients of $f(z)$, which approximates a sum of $\delta$ functions concentrated at the real roots of $f$.  A natural choice is 
$$ \phi_\epsilon(f)(t) = \sum_m\exp(-\pi|t-\lambda_m|^2/\epsilon^2). $$
I found that 
$$ \sum_m\exp(-\pi|\lambda_m|^2) =
     \iint_{\mathbb{C}}k(|z|)\log|f(z)|\,|dz|^2, 
$$
where 
$$ k(r) = 4(\pi r^2-1)e^{-\pi r^2} = 
     -2r^{-1}\frac{d}{dr}(r^2 e^{-\pi r^2}). 
$$
The more general formula
$$ \phi_\epsilon(f)(t) =
 \epsilon^{-2}\iint_{\mathbb{C}} k(|z-t|/\epsilon)\log|f(z)|\,|dz|^2 
$$
can easily be deduced from this.  I have a proof of all this, by a longish chain of fairly standard manipulations, but it is probably more complicated than necessary.

I suspect that this identity must be known, but I don't believe I have ever seen it before.  Can anyone point me to a reference?

Comment: I don't know if this is related but integrals of log|f(z)| over circles |z|=r show up in the definition of the Ronkin function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amoeba_(mathematics)#Ronkin_function .

Comment: Related to (the 1-dim case of) the Poincaré-Lelong formula (e.g. Griffiths-Harris, Lemma [p. 388](https://books.google.com/books?id=-01YBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT301))?

Comment: Different proof: Harvey [1977](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=447619), [p. 318](https://books.google.com/books?id=vKYBCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA318).

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler I agree, this can probably be deduced from the Poincaré-Lelong formula.  If you want to convert your comment to an answer then I will accept it.

Comment: Not sure I should though :-) I am also at “probably” — and maybe “overkill” too. I think you only need the very special case ($\simeq$ Cauchy integral formula) used in both refs, plus Stokes, whereupon things may well boil down to what you were doing anyway. (Harvey p. 317: Poincaré-Lelong “may be considered the most important formula in complex analysis. In combination with the Stokes theorem, one obtains the Cauchy integral theorem (...)”.)

Comment: An earlier, less-overkill reference might be Riesz ([1930](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1555311), p. 358: “Pour illustrer ces résultats...”).